# Limit of a sequence using the limit equation.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

A book I am reading contains the following statement.

Let $a_n$ be the sequence, such that
$$
a_1 = s\,, \qquad
a_{n+1} = s + c a_n^2
\quad \text{for $n = 1, 2, 3, \dots$}
$$
and assume that $s \ge 0$ and $4 c s \le 1$. Then,
$$
  a_n \le \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - 4 c s}}{2 c}
  \quad \text{for all $n \ge 1$.}
$$

The proof states that the statement follows by considering the "limit equation $a = s + c a^2$".

I have verified that $\frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - 4 c s}}{2 c}$ is the solution of the the "limit equation", but why does the above statement follow?

Answer (score 1):

Write $\theta = \dfrac{1-\sqrt{1-4cs}}{2c}$. Then $\theta = s + c\theta^2$.

You can prove that $a_n \le \theta$ for all $n \ge 1$ by induction on $n$. In the induction step, the induction hypothesis $a_n \le \theta$ implies that
$$a_{n+1} = s + ca_n^2 \le s+c\theta^2 = \theta$$
which gives you $a_{n+1} \le \theta$.

Comment: Wow, this is my 1000th answer. I should get out more.

Comment: That would be a way to proof the statement, but what is the connection to the "limit equation"? Is there a general one?

Comment: @H.Rittich: What's going on is that there is some function $f$ such that $a_{n+1} = f(a_n)$ for all $n \ge 1$, so the sequence is defined by iterating $f$. If the sequence converges, you'd expect the limit $\theta$ to satisfy $f(\theta) = \theta$—that is, the terms $a_n$ converge to a fixed point of $\theta$. That's where the 'limit equation' comes in. (Here we're just using it to come up with a bound, not a limit, but this is where the connection with fixed points comes in.)

Comment: I was expecting that it would be possible to prove the statement via some sort of contraction argument. Although, I could not come up with a proper one.

Comment: @H.Rittich: Well, the sequence is defined by recursion, so you'd expect to prove things about it by induction.